# Complement set in N

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n=f(x,y)=2xy-x-y+1 \text{ for } x,y \in N \text{ with }x>1,y>1\},$$ what is $N\backslash A$?

Can it be defined as a function such as $g(x,y)$?

Comment: Previously posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243352/how-to-figure-a-complentary-set-of-a-diophantine-equation

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer?

Comment: Yes.  I thought my comment posted but not there.  I understand your answer as A is the set such that 2n-1 is the composite numbers. And the complement is defined as n for the prime numbers.   I have several other sets similar to A that accurately define the composites. So I am wondering if it's possible to define the complement of f(x,y) to lead to a precise function to list the nth prime.

Comment: Your comment was deleted because you posted it as an answer, which it wasn't. Anyway, "complement of $f(x,y)$" doesn't make any sense, as it is sets that have complements, not functions. If you are interested in formulas for primes, I suggest starting with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen all the formulas for primes. I'll investigate new ideas on my own.

Comment: Another question is there a simple function for number of unique values for f(x,y) <= n ?

Comment: You want a simple formula for the number of composites up to $n$? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I realize it's never been done. Makes it more intriguing. I could share more info offline if interested.

Comment: Why don't you try something easier, like curing cancer, or ending world hunger, or bringing peace to the Middle East?

Comment: Those are next :)

Answer (score 1):

$n=2xy-x-y+1$, $2n-1=4xy-2x-2y+1=(2x-1)(2y-1)$ so $2n-1$ is a product of two integers, each greater than 1 ($x>1$ implies $2x-1>1$). Thus, the numbers $2n-1$ are precisely the odd composites. So $A$ is the set of all $n$ such that $2n-1$ is composite, and its complement is the set of all $n$ such that $2n-1$ is prime (together with $n=1$). To put it another way, it's the set of all integers of the form $(p+1)/2$ where $p$ is an odd prime (together with the number 1).

"Can it be defined as a function $g(x,y)$?" How do you define a set as a function?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$n \in A$ iff $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{N}, x>1, y>1$ such that $n = 2xy-x-y+1$.

Can you negate this to produce what is the equivalent of $n \not \in A$?